# Looking for a rigorous derivation of the work - energy theorem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

I'm currently trying to derive the work - energy theorem from the definition of the line integral of a vector field, but I'm having some (probabiliy silly) trouble with variables. It is known to me that:
$$W=\int_{\gamma}{\bf F}=\int_{a}^{b}{\bf F}({\bf r}(t))\cdot d{\bf r}(t)=
\int_{a}^{b}{\bf F}({\bf r}(t))\cdot{\bf r}'(t)\,dt.$$

From this, applying Newton's Second Law,
$$W=m\int_{a}^{b}{\bf a}({\bf r}(t))\cdot{\bf v}(t)\,dt
=m\int_{a}^{b}\frac{d{\bf v}({\bf r}(t))}{d{\bf r}(t)}\cdot{\bf v}(t)\,dt
$$

And this is where I'm stuck. I know how I should get on with the proof, since there's a lot of material online, but I don't know how to deal with the fact that the first velocity is a function of ${\bf r}(t)$ and the second one is only a function of $t$. Many of the proofs that I read so far showed that ${\bf F}(r(t)) = m {\bf a}(t)$ without actually facing the problem of the change of variables. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think perhaps you may just be confused with notation. $F(r(t))=ma(t)=m\frac{dv}{dt}=m\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}$. At no point should you end up with $\frac{dv}{dr}$. Does that help?

Comment: This may help - Part 1 of David Tong's lectures on Classical Dynamics - [Newtonian Mechanics](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics/one.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

It is not a mathematical problem of a change of variable but a conceptual issue related to the meaning of Newton's Second Law.

The second law
$$
\frac{{\mathrm d}^2 {\bf r}}{{\mathrm d} t^2}(t)=\frac{{\bf F}}{m}
$$
explicitly establishes the time dependence of the second time derivative of the position (the acceleration), which is a function of time only, on the time dependence of the right-hand side of the equation, where all the time dependence of the acceleration, through the relevant variables should be explicitly given (to have a solvable problem).

In the case of a force depending only on ${\bf r}(t)$, the proper writing is
$$
{\bf a}(t)=\frac{{\bf F}({\bf r}(t))}{m}=\frac{{\mathrm d} {\bf v}}{{\mathrm d} t}(t)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The following isn't a rigorous derivation, but I think it can serve as the basis of one. That is, the purpose of the following is not to provide an exhaustive answer, but to try and get you unstuck.

I find it remarkable that it uses an integral with $dt$ as intermediary step to arrive at an expression that has no explicit time variable.

My preference is to first work out an expression for the integral of acceleration over distance, and only then combine with $F=ma$

The work-energy theorem has mathematics content and physics content. This order of operation, with introduction of physics postponed until the very last step, emphasizes that distinction

$$ ds = v \ dt \qquad (1) $$

$$ dv = a \ dt \qquad (2) $$

Integral of acceleration over distance:

$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds \qquad (3) $$

Intermediary step: change of the differential according to (1), with corresponding change of limits.

$$ \int_{t_0}^t a \ v \ dt \qquad (4) $$

Change the order:

$$ \int_{t_0}^t v \ a \ dt \qquad (5) $$

Change of differential according to (2), with corresponding change of limits.

$$ \int_{v_0}^v v \ dv \qquad (6) $$

Putting everything together:

$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2 \qquad (7) $$

Multiplying both sides with $m$ to arrive at the work-energy theorem:

$$ \int_{s_0}^s F \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}mv_0^2 \qquad (8) $$